# CSS block elements creating gaps between div elements

Tags: css, html, spacing

I'm having difficulties with spaces between div blocks:

```
<div id="maincontentwrapper" >
  <img src="images/content-top.png" alt="main content border image" border="1" />
  <div id="maincontent" >
    <div id="pagecontent">
       <h1>Mission Statement</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="images/content-bottom.png" alt="main content border image" />
</div>
```

This is creating a page with a full bordered image. All is well, however as soon as I enter a block level element inside of pagecontent, e.g. the header as shown, then a gap appears between the content-top.png image and the maincontent div.

If I change the first character to be inline, e.g. a non-breaking space or simply a letter, then the gap does not appear.

This is the (relevant) css:

```
img {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#maincontentwrapper { 
}
#maincontent {
 background-image: url('../../images/content-main.png');
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 min-height: 300px;
 width: 757px;
}
#pagecontent {
 width: 625px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: alt="main content border image"? Seriously? Go and read http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html right now!

Comment: It's a case piece of html at the minute :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a margin applied by the browser by default. Try your code with

```
h1 { margin: 0; }
```

added to the CSS. Does that help?

(The `h1` element is not the only block-level element to "suffer" from this, `p` has default margins in most browsers too.)

If you're pretty sure your client's browser will support CSS3, you have a backup mechanism, or you just don't care, you could do

```
.maincontent :first-child, .maincontent :first-child :first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

which will set the first child's margin to 0, regardless of the type of the element.

Something else you *could* do is apply a ["reset stylesheet"](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) that undoes the browsers' defaults by masking them with zeroes. However, I would not advise you to do so, since the browsers' defaults actually make sense most of the time, and resetting them all could lead to disturbing effects.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks. 

I guess I need to learn more about the box model as I assumed it would simply add a margin to the header within the div block it's in not the outer block.

The reason it looked so bad is I have a background on the body and that margin on the header was creating a 10 pixel white block across the whole page.

Comment: I mean a 10 pixel gap across the page. Is there a better way than resetting every element's margin?

Comment: The css fixed it. It works for IE8, Chrome and FF3.6. I'm getting it tested on others to see how it goes. Thanks very much. However, I still don't understand how the block element adds a gap and leaves a hole beneath when I thought it would be increasing the block it is in not the blocks outside of it :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another element than a H1? I believe the problem comes from the H1 element having margins by default and maybe that's what "pushing" the div down and leaving a gap. By the way, are you using Firefox's plugin [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to test CSS? It's really powerful and lets you modify on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a problem due to browser default css settings, like those applied to h1 p, etc.

One way to get rid of this is to use some "reset" css like the one in 960grid : [here](http://960.gs/)

From my experience, it works fine :)

Comment: Thanks. As above that was the case, but the problem I have is how best to best fix it to stop other elements, other than resetting everything to a zero margin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because margins are collapsing. Try to add

```
padding: 0 1px 0 1px;
```

to img or div or both.

Comment: setting the margin to 0 for the header fixed it, as above. But I guess how do I fix it for any other element?

Answer (score 0):

The `<img />` tag is rendered inline by default. Try `display: block`.